# How to make a sticky footer?

Tags: theme-development

The footer does not stay on the bottom.

```
 footer {
           padding:2em;
           bottom:0;
           clear:both;
           background-color:black;
           color:white;
           position:absolute;
        }
```

does not work and neither does `postion:relative;`.. What do I do?

Comment: This is not a WordPress question. This is a CSS Question. You could have applied to CSS directly to the footer itself.

Comment: Why asking a (off-topic) question which you answer yourself innerhalve a few minits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer. In your footer.php file add a div like that goes outside the footer and assign your footer class to it. For example,

`<div class="sticky-footer">
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
        <div class="site-info">
            <?php
                /* translators: 1: Theme name, 2: Theme author. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'best' ), 'best', '<a href="http://underscores.me/">Underscores.me</a>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->
</div>`

And the correct style is :

```
.sticky-footer {
    padding:2em;
    bottom:0;
    clear:both;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    position:static;
    width:100%;
}
```